# try and catch java with files in a GUI

Tags: java, file, user-interface, try-catch

```
private class PrintButtonListener implements ActionListener{    
    public void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            if (e.getSource() == radio){
                try{
                    File file = new File("Birds.txt");
                    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
                    area.setText(inputFile.toString());
                    }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    System.out.println("File not found!");
                }
            }

        }
  }
```

I need to display 2 different files. Each file has an associated radio button. The content of the files must display on the GUI interface once the button is clicked. I really need help with this one!

```
    private JRadioButton radio; // first radio button
    private JRadioButton radio2; // second radio button
    private JRadioButton radio3; // third radio button

    private JButton button; // button to gain access to whatever option was selected

    private JPanel panel; // the panel

    private JTextArea area;

    private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;

    public BirdTest2(){ // GUI constructor
        super();
        setSize(2000,950);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);
    }

    public void buildPanel(){ // building the panel for the GUI
        panel = new JPanel();

        radio = new JRadioButton("Display all birds!");
        radio2 = new JRadioButton("Display foreign birds only!");
        radio3 = new JRadioButton("Display non-foreign birds only!");

        button = new JButton("Click me!");
        button.addActionListener(new PrintButtonListener());

        buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        buttonGroup.add(radio);
        buttonGroup.add(radio2);
        buttonGroup.add(radio3);

        area = new JTextArea();

        panel.add(radio);
        panel.add(radio2);
        panel.add(radio3);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(area);
    }
```

Here is the code I have above the previous for my window, button, radio buttons. Help would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need any additional info :)

Comment: I do have 3 radio buttons made however if I can get just 2 working at least that would be fine. One I need to use a remove method from a linked list so that would be the third.

Comment: What is the main class for this code?

Comment: All I have at the moment is:

Comment: BirdTest2 app = new BirdTest2();

Comment: Can you show the signature for this class: `public class BirdTest2 ...`

Comment: public class BirdTest2 extends JFrame{

Comment: Then inside is all the code I have posted here

Answer (score 0):

> The content of the files must display on the GUI interface once the button is clicked.

To read a File using Scanner, you have to explicitly iterate over all the lines of the file using the methods defined by the Scanner object you are using (the `toString` currently used in actionPerformed will only return a String representing the Scanner object, which isn't necessarily the contents of the File).

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
while ( inputFile.hasNextLine() ){
    area.append(inputFile.nextLine());//append the line to the JTextArea
    area.append("\n");//append any new lines as they are ommitted with Scanner.nextLine
}
```

You can check which JCheckBox is selected in the actionPerformed method to determine which File to open based upon which JCheckBox is selected.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and let you know my result :)

Comment: Nothing displays, what could be the reason?